# How to save image to sdcard when using Fresco?

Tags: android, bitmap, fresco

I am using [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/) to download and display Gifs in my app. I want to save the image to sdcard when click it, but i can't figure out how to do it.

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gif_viewer, container, false);
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl);
DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
        .setUri(uri)
        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
        .build();
draweeView.setController(controller);

draweeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Save the gif to /sdcard/test.gif
    }
});
```

I try to get the bitmap from the SimpleDraweeView following the instruction of [How do I save an ImageView as an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262598/how-do-i-save-an-imageview-as-an-image), but it's `getDrawingCache()` returns null

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
ImageRequest downloadRequest = ImageRequest.fromUri(uri);
CacheKey cacheKey = DefaultCacheKeyFactory.getInstance().getEncodedCacheKey(downloadRequest);
if (ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().getMainDiskStorageCache().hasKey(cacheKey)) {
    BinaryResource resource = ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().getMainDiskStorageCache().getResource(cacheKey);
    File cacheFile = ((FileBinaryResource) resource).getFile();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
    ImageFormat imageFormat = ImageFormatChecker.getImageFormat(fis);
    switch (imageFormat) {
        case GIF:
        //copy cacheFile to sdcard
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you test this answer? it fails with nullpointer exception

Comment: It works on my project.Make sure this GIF is fetched on disk cache.

Comment: The API changed you should use ```getMainFileCache()``` instead of ```getMainDiskStorageCache()```. This will return the whole cache. However this will give you the stored file in the Fresco cache rather than a file that you can display.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the image pipeline directly](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-image-pipeline.html#skipping-the-decode) to extract your GIF from disk cache.

Then you can use Java File methods to write it to the file system.

Comment: I know how to use the image pipeline to save static pics such as png.But when comes to gif, it's different.

Comment: As Allen mentioned gifs are considered 'animations' so they cannot be extracted in the same way.