# How to get Bitmap from SimpleDraweeView?

Tags: android, bitmap, fresco

I want to get `Bitmap` from `SimpleDraweeView` of Fresco lib, and save it to SD Card.
`SimpleDraweeView` is child class of `ImageView` so it should support `getDrawable()` but calling this method throws `ClassCastException`

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) viewHolder.drawee.getDrawable();

ClassCastException: com.facebook.drawee.generic.RootDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
```

What is the wayout for this?

Comment: Can you explain with respect to the main diagram on this page: http://frescolib.org/docs/intro-image-pipeline.html what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: After bitmap is rendered on SimpleDraweeView, that is the last stage, I want to extract the Image on View as bitmap.

Comment: Found this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/q/30751577/295004 and this answer looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31769964/295004

Comment: Thanks Morrison for your effort. I will test this and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s1rius's answer mentioned by Morrison helped me. Here's the code that I used.

```
ImageRequest downloadRequest = ImageRequest.fromUri(uri);

CacheKey cacheKey = DefaultCacheKeyFactory.getInstance().getEncodedCacheKey(downloadRequest, context);

if (ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().getMainFileCache().hasKey(cacheKey)) {
     BinaryResource resource = ImagePipelineFactory.getInstance().getMainFileCache().getResource(cacheKey);
     File cacheFile = ((FileBinaryResource) resource).getFile();
     File savedImageFile = new File(Constants.APP_PATH_SAVED_QUOTES, "M1iS1" + "_" + currentPosition + ".jpg");
}
```

Then I copied `cacheFile` into `savedImageFile`.